# How often does the word "truth" appear n the Torah?

Tags: language

I am interested in knowing how often the word "truth" or "emet appears in the Torah

Comment: that might be hard to answer

Comment: do you mean all of tanach, or only the חמישי חומשי תורה

Comment: just the five books

Comment: For a-m-t in that order, plus any prefixes or suffices, meaning some version of rectitude or truth, I count 10.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: But not only might there be appearances of the root with infixes, but there are also other words which point to similar concepts. I just don't know if they would "count" because you seemed to limit to "emet."

Comment: I vote to close 
based on https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5272/1739

Comment: I recommend using a concordance.

Answer (score 1):

How many times does אמת appear in the Torah?

**11-Times from [Genesis, Exodus, Leviticus, Numbers, Deuteronomy].** If this answer is not אמת please let me know.

- Genesis 24:27 [MT]
- Genesis 24:48 [MT]
- Genesis 24:49 [MT]
- Genesis 32:11 [MT]
- Genesis 42:16 [MT]
- Genesis 47:29 [MT]
- Exodus 18:21 [MT]
- Exodus 34:6 [MT]
- Deuteronomy 13:15 [MT]
- Deuteronomy 17:4 [MT]
- Deuteronomy 22:20 [MT]

Comment: Amito in Gen 24:27 may not be "truth" as much as "faithfulness." The same could be said about other uses of a-m-t, that they don't mean "truth" in a literal sense.

Answer (score 0):

the english word "truth" appears 3 times in Genesis, 0 times in Exodus, 0 times in Leviticus, 0 times in Numbers, and 0 times in Deuteronomy acording to Sefaria's English translations

Comment: this might not be correct according to other translations

Answer (score 0):

In Talmudic tradition, truth is the seal of God.